# GDI + Generic error only on specific case [C#]

Tags: c#, image, drag-and-drop, gdi+

**tldr:**
I have one function that draws image that I save later.

I can save file in every possible scenario except when I drag image to exe while that image is not in the same folder. Dragged image just feeds string path to the function.

**/tldr**

I have a function that draws image in Picture Box on Windows Forms.
This function accepts string - path, and then processes the data.

When user drops picture on form, I send path from dropped file to my function and it draws file just fine.

Then I hit save button which contains next code :

```
Bitmap tmpOutputSave = new Bitmap(pbOutput.Image);
 tmpOutputSave.Save("Generisano\\Image" + tmpDate + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

And I save the image.

Everything works fine.

If I open my application in D:\some_path\MyApplication\myapp.exe and I drag image file from Desktop, I will see the image in picturebox, and when I hit save - everything works fine.

If I drag image file from same folder to myapp.exe, and hit save - everything works fine too, and I can see the image in picturebox.

However, in this second case, if I drag image from any other folder to myapp.exe, image will load as well but when I try to save I will get "Generic error in GDI+".

Code that I'm using to get path from dragged file to exe is :

program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1(args));



   }
}
```

form1.cs

```
public Form1(string[] args) {     


        InitializeComponent();
        sablon = new Sablon(this);

        LoadSettings();
        pbOutput.MouseWheel += pbOutput_MouseWheel;

        if (args.Count() > 0) { 
            try
            { 
            imgPath = args[0];
            pbOutput.Image = Crtaj.Sliku(imgPath);
            hadFirstArgument = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

Notes : Crtaj.Sliku is : Class : Crtaj, with function Sliku - which accepts string to draw image.

So to sum up :
 - It's the same function for all cases
 - Dragging on form from any location works fine
 - Dragging on exe from same folder works fine
 - Dragging on exe from another folder doesn't work
 - Paths are same in all cases, image is same in all cases

Only difference is that I try to drag and drop file from another folder on exe (no problem if I do it on form, even though code and paths are the same).

I saw many topics about this, but I didn't really see specific issue related to mine, I'm sorry if I oversaw something.

What could be the problem ? 
I'm sure that it's not illegal characters or file location - because I format characters before saving, I'm sure that folder exists and paths are the same too.

Thank you!

Comment: tl;dr but if the image is open in the second case, you cannot save to the same file name.

Comment: Thanks fore reply Plutonix.
I'm not trying to overwrite file, I save it in new location with unique name.
I'm also trying to save newly created image from pictureBox, by the time picture shows up, function is done completely with file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it using an absolute path? Like setting the savefile location to somewhere like;

```
C:\Temp\Test.png
```

Or somewhere that you know exists. If you're generating the save path (even if it's with the same code), the resulting folders might be different in your two cases, and it may fail to save the file because of that. I remember losing some hair because of that a few years ago. If that happens to be the case, you'll only need to look into why the generated path points to an incorrect location.